# "Daylight Savings Time" in DOS

Tags: c, dos, ctime, watcom

I am using the `time(NULL)` function in a C application to get the seconds since 1970. I've noticed that it is returning the information with 1 hour of difference.

then I tried to convert the result to a `tm`structure using `localtime`, and then I noticed that the `tm_isdst` field is being set.

The code is like this:

```
time_t tempo;
struct tm sttime;

memset( &sttime, 0, sizeof( sttime ) );

tempo = time( NULL );  

printf( "%d\n", tempo );

sttime = *( localtime( &tempo ) );    
sttime.tm_isdst = 0;
tempo = mktime( &sttime );

printf( "%d\n", tempo );
```

In the first `printf`, `tempo`is being print with one hour of difference. In the second, it is printing the correct value.

I am running the application in a `Ms DOS 6.0` OS, and the application is being compiled with `Watcom v1.3`.

Where is the `Daylight Savings Time` information coming from?  Does DOS hold this info?

Comment: When I try running your code on Linux, I'm seeing an hour of difference also:

Comment: This answer may shed some light on the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57713857/3857942

Answer (score 0):

By clearing `sttime.tm_isdst` you're telling `mktime` that it's an hour later than it actually is (if you're in DST, which it seems to be that you are since you say `sttime.tm_isdst` is set).

Comment: What I am wondering is why it is returning DST, because it is not DST in my region now.

Comment: My guess is that these values might be hardcoded into DOS (contrasted with a zoneinfo kind of model). Since timezone/daylight saving time is arbitrarily defined (by some government body), it's definition in your area might have changed in the 20 or so years since MSDOS 6.0 was released.