# How to set (or correct for) timezone & DST in c (time.h functions) and DOS

Tags: c, x86, dos, localtime, time.h

I have a computer running DOS (freeDos 1.1) and plain C (compiled with Borland 5.0) with `time.h`.  When I set the computer time using BIOS or the `DATE` and `TIME` DOS commands, there is no information about time zone.  I set the time to my current time 10:25 AM.

My C program does this...

```
char timeString[80];
time_t timeT = time(NULL);
strftime(timeString, sizeof(timeString), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", localtime(&timeT));
printf("%s\n", timeString);
```

when I run the code I get the correct current time but with a "EST" time zone at the end as called by the `%Z` formatter.

Mon 2017-03-13 10:25:36 EST

The returned `time_t` value from `time(NULL)` is 1489418736.
This mathematically breaks down to 47 years, 83 days, 15 hours, 25 minutes, 36 seconds
Clearly `time.h` is implementing some time zone information here, adding 5 hours to my current time.

Moving over to javascript which receives the `time_t` value

```
new Date(1489418736 * 1000)
```

Mon Mar 13 2017 08:25:36 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

It seems there is some combination of time zone (EST vs PST vs GMT) and daylight savings time (which might account for the extra hour?) at play here.  How can I affect the time zone and DST settings of the machine, operating system, or C library representation, to get the most useful time representation whether that be local or GMT?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for. If that is about some DOS command, it is  off-topic here. For programming, provide a [mcve] and describe your specific problem. The basic question might be: "Does DOS support timezones?"

Comment: I'm curious why you have a DOS machine.  The last DOS release was 16 years ago.  A blast from the past, to be sure.

Comment: I've changed the title to reflect better the question being asked (was already last sentence of post).  Why I'm using DOS, because that's the project I'm assigned.  Why the question is unclear, because I'm totally unclear at what level this is implemented whether it be machine, os, c library, or just my usage of it.

Comment: With DOS it was usually just assumed you set the clock according to your local time zone... there wasn't really any time zone related functionality (if there ever was, it was rarely used).

Comment: @Amy: That is not quite true. FreeDOS is still maintained and available for new PCs. Although Linux would most likely be a better choice today for production systems.

Comment: I have a vague memory of an environment variable `TZ`, and of the old MS-DOS Borland Turbo C compiler having some connection with it for its time functions. See if `SET TZ` tells you anything.

Comment: What operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: editing question with this - freeDos 1.1 and Borland C++ 5.0

Answer (score 0):

It's been many years, but I think there's a DOS environment variable that C looks for to determine the timezone. C may default to EST if it doesn't find the environment variable. I can't speak to the javascript aspects of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning daylight issues, code is going to have troubles.  In US, "my current time 10:25 AM should have been "Mon 2017-03-13 10:25:36 EDT" (EDT vs EST).  The quaint TurboC code is certainly going to have troubles with the evolved DST rules that have differed over the decades.

IMO, any use of TurboC `localtime()`, `mktime()`, `struct tm.isdst` field and `_daylight` will all yield unsatisfactory results concerning daylight savings time and  likely be an endless source of timezone issues.  Either use a modern compiler/library or import/roll your own (ugh) timezone/daylight routines.

Alternative, stick to `time_t` and universal time - no local time

Comment: maybe my question is too convoluted to get this, but even the time_t value seems to be affected, having 5 hours in addition to the time set in DOS.  I suppose I should just subtract 5 hours from it and call it a day since like you say I likely can't truly fix it.

Comment: As others have commented, the "DOS" sense of time was usually "local time" and the conversion to universal depends on knowing the timezone _and_ the DST setting.  As computers were not so mobile, the timezone was reasonable constant.  Unfortunate, the DST shift, or not, was often set up algorithmically (per some fixed rule) and that rule was not amenable to sporadic [updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States#Extension_of_daylight_saving_time_.281975.E2.80.931986.29).  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

DOS (including FreeDOS) has no notion of time zones. These OSes were designed with a simple end user in mind, not database design, mission critical apps, timestamp logging, the PC being in other timezones etc. In the end, the designers of these OSes took the path of least resistance. Everything was in the user's local time.

When C compilers started being written to conform to the Standard C API, there was a problem with implementing `gmtime` on DOS. DOS users set their PC to local time, not UTC. Unfortunately, you can't reliably convert a local time to UTC because of DST issues (you can reliably convert UTC to any local time), but the developers wanted a solution. They chose to ignore the issues that may arise with converting local time to UTC and allowed you to set the `TZ` environment variable to specify the conversion from local time to UTC.

In the absence of the `TZ` being set libraries defaulted to a timezone which often happened to be EST, which is the case with the Borland compilers. That is why you see EST being returned as the timezone by `localtime`.

Before running your application (preferably you set it in `autoexec.bat` at boot) you can use the `set TZ=` command to specify the conversion from local time to UTC. A good article on syntax of the `TZ` variable can be found [here](https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/software/winvn/userguide/3_1_4.htm):

```
set TZ=tzn[+|-]hh[:mm[:ss] ][dzn]
```

`TZN` is the 3 letter time zone identifier for standard local time, and `DZN` is the 3 letter identifier for daylight savings time. `TZN` and `DZN` are used for display purposes. If `DZN` is omitted then this flags that daylight savings time doesn't apply to your time zone. The most important part is the offset (+/-) which specifies the amount of time to be added or subtracted from **standard** local time to convert it to UTC.

As an example, I'm in Mountain Standard Time (MST) and daylight savings time applies (MDT). MST is 7 hours behind UTC so 7 has to be added to my standard local time to get UTC. I'd set my timezone this way:

```
set TZ=MST7MDT
```

If I was in Newfoundland where standard time (NST) is 3.5 hours behind UTC and daylight savings time applies then I could use:

```
set TZ=NST3:30NDT
```

If I was in Saskatchewan, Canada that uses Central Standard Time (CST is 6 hours behind UTC) where daylight saving time doesn't apply then I'd use:

```
set TZ=CST6
```

---

### My Recommendation - Use UTC in DOS

I have personally found in embedded systems where the OS isn't time zone aware, that it is easier to set the system clock to UTC instead of local time. You then write software to convert UTC to local time based on some software configuration if need be. This has the advantage that you can write the rules for DST. The rules for DST built into the Borland libraries no longer apply a generation later. Using UTC is also useful for timestamping event logs since you can express unambiguous times. In this situation I use:

```
set TZ=UTC0
```

which effectively makes local time the same as UTC.

---

### DST Differences Between Products

At the time most of the Borland products were developed the rule employed for DST was for the US market. From 1987 through 2006 DST ran from the first Sunday of April to the last Sunday of October. After 2006 it was changed in the US to run from the second Sunday in March to the first Sunday in November.

The reason Borland C++ 5 (releases issued between 1996-1997) showed EST (and not EDT) was because from its perspective DST in 2017 didn't start until Sunday April 2nd, 2017 (first Sunday of April), so it still believed Monday March 13th, 2017 was still on Standard Time. The environment in which your Javascript ran is likely aware (based on modern underlying Time Zone databases and rules) that in 2017 DST came into effect on March 12th, 2017 (second Sunday in March) so it showed Monday March 13th, 2017 in Daylight Time (PDT). I will assume that Pacific Time was used because the system running the Javascript was told you are in a Pacific Time Zone that observes DST.